# How to use a (repeating) aggregate function value with other columns from the table I use the aggregate function on

Tags: postgresql

Problem: I have to count the number of times a certain user has a  certificate and then return the users name, his number of certificates and the difference between the maximum number of certificates across all users and this specific users number of certificates. I succeeded in the first part (getting the number of certificates) which I'll denote as $*query*$ (because I have a feeling my problem has something to do with aliasing).

So $*query*$ looks like this:

```
User        |N_Certificates
Geoff         4
Ann           2
Lisa          0
```

And my end result should look like this:

```
User        |N_Certificates |Difference
Geoff         4              0
Ann           2              2
Lisa          0              4
```

I tried this query:

```
     SELECT Sub.name, Sub.N_Certificates,
     MAX(Sub.N_Certificates)-  Sub.Certificates AS Difference FROM ($_query_$) AS SUB
```

but it returned a error (because I was trying to use an aggregate function in combination with a column I was not grouping by) or a wrong result (notably, difference=0 for all columns).

I tried a contraption with INNER JOIN on another version of sub (same $*query*$ code with another alias) but it also didn't work (same reason). I could ofcourse hard code the max but I don't think that's a good solution. My about screen tells me I'm using version 1.18 of pg_Admin.

Comment: I think aggregate functions work best with the HAVING clause...

Comment: But what would that change? Isn't having a restriction on GROUP BY the purpose of HAVING? The aggregate function is actually a constant here. There are also no results to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in this way, SQL syntax doesn't allow this.
The easiest way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT Sub.name, Sub.N_Certificates,
     (SELECT MAX(Sub.N_Certificates) FROM ($_query_$))
      -  
     Sub.Certificates AS Difference 
FROM ($_query_$) AS SUB
```

---

You can also use a common table expression:

```
WITH some_alias AS(
   SELECT * FROM ($_query_$)
)
SELECT name, N_Certificates.
       (SELECT MAX(N_Certificates)FROM some_alias)
          -  
       Certificates AS Difference    
FROM some_alias
```

---

And you can use a windows function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

```
SELECT Sub.name, Sub.N_Certificates,
       MAX(Sub.N_Certificates) OVER ()
       -  
       Sub.Certificates AS Difference 
FROM ($_query_$) AS SUB
```

Comment: This solution worked. Thank you for taking the time to answer. So, with the way I aliased I wasn't able to call upon the table without specificaly addressing it I guess (I tried something similiar but it was looking horrible since I had to copy paste the query everytime). Will try to use WITH more in the future.